# Could not enable Windows Firewall on windows vista?

Tags: windows-vista, firewall

I tried to activate the Windows Firewall on windows vista but it says the related service is not started.

What is the related service to start Windows Firewall?

Someone helps me :)

Thank you,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the service is called "Windows Firewall"
you can find it with Win+R > services.msc

Comment: I enable the service, it says again impossible. "please contact the provider with the the reference code 6801" :-s